# Skip mounting of nfs after three attempts

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, nfs, fstab, rhel-6

I am using RHEL 6.5 in my company and using a file server(NFS).

I have put a mount point address to file server in the client's fstab file like this

```
10.9.9.25:/opt/Files /opt/Files    nfs     defaults        0 0
```

I want the client to attempt mounting the NFS file system 3 times before it fails. What configuration should I use?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, as far as I know, define a maximum number of attempts, instead use **`retry=2`** as an option to specify a 2 minute time-out:

```
10.9.9.25:/opt/Files /opt/Files    nfs     defaults,retry=2        0 0
```

[`man nfs`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/nfs)

> **`retry=n`**        The number of minutes that the mount(8) command retries an NFS mount  operation  in  the  fore‐
>                         ground  or background before giving up.  If this option is not specified, the default value for
>                         foreground mounts is 2 minutes, and the default value for background mounts  is  10000  minutes
>                         (80  minutes  shy  of  one  week).  If a value of zero is specified, the mount(8) command exits
>                         immediately after the first failure.